# I gave a 2.2 TB hard disk but only 100GB (sda->sda3->ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv) mounted in /

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partition

I have ubuntu 22.04 server on my vm in esxi and iam new for this

The size of my current directory(`/home/<username>`) after login is only 100GB

```
df -h .
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   98G   11G   83G  12% /
```

I gave a 2.2 TB hard disk but only 100GB (sda->sda3->ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv) mounted in `/`. Here is the `lsblk` result

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0   62M  1 loop /snap/core20/1611
loop1                       7:1    0 67.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22753
loop2                       7:2    0   47M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16292
loop3                       7:3    0 63.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/2182
loop4                       7:4    0 91.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24061
sda                         8:0    0  2.2T  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0    2G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0  2.2T  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  100G  0 lvm  /
sdb                         8:16   0  500G  0 disk
└─sdb1                      8:17   0  500G  0 part /tg-rootdir
sr0                        11:0    1  1.3G  0 rom
```

And here is the`df -h` result

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               504G     0  504G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              101G  1.5M  101G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   98G   11G   83G  12% /
tmpfs                              504G     0  504G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              504G     0  504G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1611
/dev/sda2                          2.0G  106M  1.7G   6% /boot
/dev/loop1                          68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/22753
/dev/loop2                          47M   47M     0 100% /snap/snapd/16292
tmpfs                              101G     0  101G   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop3                          64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/2182
/dev/loop4                          92M   92M     0 100% /snap/lxd/24061
/dev/sdb1                          492G   95G  372G  21% /tg-rootdir
```

and this is the disk path in the General Information Tab of the VM

```
Disk Path     Capacity   Free
/             97.87 GB   82.59 GB (84%)
/boot         1.9 GB     1.68 GB (88%)
/tg-rootdir   491.08 GB  340.17 GB (69%)
```

So I want the remaining unused disk on `sda3` to be put in the same place as the 100GB one so that `/home/<username>` becomes bigger.
Should I create a new partition from `sda3` or just extend the ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv? or any suggestion?

Thank you
Best Regards,

Comment: yah, its same with my friend suggestion, i use lvresize and resize2fs. Thanks